# puppet and manifest loops

Tags: puppet

How can I access elements of an array in puppet manifests i.e. create a for/while loop? Let's say I have in my nodes.pp

```
Name [ 'testserver', 'floor1', 'floor3' ],
```

How can I iterate over that so that when I define my file resource I can iterate over each and ensure correct file resources exist for each element?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no way to do a loop in the traditional sense, but you can probably still achieve what you're going for.  An array, when used as a resource title, will be automatically expanded.

So for a simple case, you'd just have an array like

```
$packages = [ 'httpd', 'mysql', 'puppet' ]
```

Then use that in a resource, like:

```
package { $packages:
  ensure => installed,
}
```

For more complicated cases, you can use a defined type.  I'm not quite sure where you're going with your example - let me know if this doesn't make sense for your use case.

Say, for instance, you're sending in an array of `[ 'testserver', 'floor1', 'floor3' ]` and what you're needing to do with that list is to create a file at `/etc/foo/testserver` (for the first element), then run an `exec` to set something up once that's done.

```
define datafiles {
  file { "/etc/foo/${title}":
    ensure  => present,
    content => $title,
  }
  exec { "setup-${title}":
    command => "/usr/local/bin/something -a /etc/foo/${title}",
    require => File["/etc/foo/${title}"],
  }
}
```

Then, using the array in the title of the defined type will expand it, creating both the file and exec resources for each member of the array.

```
$names = [ 'testserver', 'floor1', 'floor3' ]
datafiles { $names: }
```

Comment: Perfect, much appreciated. Just for information can I declare a variable like $num=0 and increment it for each pass of the array through the define? Or does it get reset upon each pass of define? Thanks

Comment: @Dan Nope, that wouldn't work correctly - the declarative nature of the manifest language makes that kind of flow impossible.